# SecurityBundle use_forward after registration instead of override RegistrationController possible?

Tags: symfony

Can I use `use_forward:true` in `app/config/security.yml` similar to `form_login:` ? Or the only way to do that is to override `RegistrationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know from where comes `RegistrationController` (*maybe FosUserBundle?*) but `use_forward` is a configuration parameter available only to customize the user experience during authentication. So the answer is NO you can't use that parameter directly for any other pourpose.

If you use `FosUserBundle` (*to implement the same behavior*) I think you can only override the `RegistrationController` as [showed in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html).